# Error LNK2019 - Name Decoration - Missing __imp_

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors, lnk2019

This is probably a duplicate, but there are so many `LNK2019` questions, I can't read them all.  Here's my problem:  I'm getting the following error message:

```
4>ScatterometerView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
"__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall CPGLGraphBitDlgBSDF::CPGLGraphBitDlgBSDF(class CPGLGraph *)" (__imp_??0CPGLGraphBitDlgBSDF@@QAE@PAVCPGLGraph@@@Z) 
referenced in function "public: void __thiscall CScatterometerView::DisplayBSDFPlot(class BSDF *)" (?DisplayBSDFPlot@CScatterometerView@@QAEXPAVBSDF@@@Z)
```

When I look at the output of `DUMPBIN`, I see my **constructor**:

```
12    B 00002EFF ??0CPGLGraphBitDlgBSDF@@QAE@PAVCPGLGraph@@@Z = @ILT+7930(??0CPGLGraphBitDlgBSDF@@QAE@PAVCPGLGraph@@@Z)
```

It has everything except the `__imp__`.  The class in the **DLL** is defined as follows:

```
#define PGL_EXT_CLASS _declspec(dllexport)
class PGL_EXT_CLASS CPGLGraphBitDlgBSDF : public CPGLGraphDlg
{
public:
    static const int numPointsToAvg = 3;
    CPGLGraphBitDlgBSDF();
    CPGLGraphBitDlgBSDF(CPGLGraph* _pGraph);
    ~CPGLGraphBitDlgBSDF(void);
    // ...lots more functions...
}
```

and the usage in the executable is:

```
CPGLGraph* pGraph = new CPGLGraph;
// ...code to fill in the graph data...
m_bsdf_plot = new CPGLGraphBitDlgBSDF(pGraph);
```

The kicker is that every other function in the class works; only the two I added recently (including this constructor) don't work.  The older functions don't have the `__imp__` decoration that seems to be required of my newly added functions.

The `.def` files that were created define no functions, so this doesn't seem to be a difference.  I used the `MAP file` on the linker, and the only functions that have the `__imp__` prefix are those defined by Microsoft.  Not a single function defined in **PGL.dll** has it, and they all work fine.  Please tell me where to look for the problem or even clues.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma once
#if defined DLL_EXPORT
#define MY_API_NAME __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MY_API_NAME __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Normally that stands in your .hpp from your DLL. You need to define DLL_EXPORT in the preprocessor settings from the DLL project, so the functions will be exported when building the DLL and imported, when it is used in a different project.

Comment: Good point.  My code is based on PGL (Plot Graphics Library), and code almost exactly like yours already exists in PGL.h, which is #included in my file.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I am not sure, but try to export the functions of the class all manually. Like write your PGL_EXT_CLASS in front of the constructor/destructor/functions. Maybe there is something in the class wich cant be exported, happened to me a time ago.

Comment: Another good idea!  Unfortunately, when I tried it I got the following error message:  "A member of a class declared with dllexport/dllimport cannot itself be declared with such a specifier".  So it is now certain that the class is declared with dllexport and that I cannot employ your latest suggestion.  At least I learned something.

Comment: When you export the functions manually, you must remove PGL_EXT_GLASS in `class PGL_EXT_CLASS CPGLGraphBitDlgBSDF` my fault :)